# PHP: How to modify an array from inside foreach loop (by reference)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify an array's values by a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733290/how-to-modify-an-arrays-values-by-a-foreach-loop)

Why doesn't this work?

```
$user_list_array = array(
    1 => array( "first_name" => "Jim" ),
    2 => array( "first_name" => "Bob" )
)

foreach ($user_list_array as $item ) {
    echo $item["first_name"];
    $item["last_name"] = "test";
} 

var_dump($user_list_array );
```

I can get the "first_name"s back, but can't add the "last_name";

Comment: Because you're just modifying the $item variable which was created within the foreach loop, you're not actually modifying the original array.

Comment: Ahh. Is there an elegant way to do this correctly?

Comment: I have to number a big list of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're modifying $item, which is a copy of the relevant entry fro $user_list_array

**EITHER:**
(modify the original array)

```
foreach ($user_list_array as $key => $item ) { 
    echo $item["first_name"]; 
    $user_list_array[$key]["last_name"] = "test"; 
}
```

**OR:**
(by reference)

```
foreach ($user_list_array as &$item ) { 
    echo $item["first_name"]; 
    $item["last_name"] = "test"; 
} 
unset($item);
```

Comment: You would not happend to have a benchmark on the performance between the two ?

Comment: No I don't have a benchmark, though easy enough to run. At a guess, I'd think it would be the "by reference" option, because it doesn't need to handle both key and value in the foreach; but that is just a guess

Comment: @MarkBaker Without knowing the exact stats, do you thinks it's problematic to loop over 1000 users this way? I know foreach loops can slow things down, but I don't know how else to do this.

Comment: Loops are a natural part of most programming languages, and shouldn't be avoided purely because there's a risk of slow execution... any potential performance issue is dependent on what's done in the loop. In this case, a simple echo and simple modification of the array entry isn't a great deal, even over 1000 iterations. A third option, which might be slightly faster in some cases would be using array_map() or array_walk() with a closure; but I don't honestly think you need to worry excessively in this case

Comment: You can change the main arrray but **NOT** in the current loop; we can change next item of array like: `$A=[3,2,1]; foreach($A as $k=>$v){ if($k==1) $A[2]=4; echo "\nk=".$k." v=".$v; }`

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($user_list_array as &$item ) {
    echo $item["first_name"];
    $item["last_name"] = "test";
}
```

Adding & before $item will pass the array by reference which means that any modifications you make to it will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because you were not modifying the actual array, this should do the trick.

```
$user_list_array = array(
    1 => array( "first_name" => "Jim" ),
    2 => array( "first_name" => "Bob" )
)

foreach ($user_list_array as $id => $item ) { 
    echo $item["first_name"]; 
    $user_list_array[$id]["last_name"] = "test"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be modifying the original array, not the tmp variable `$item` the loop creates. You could do it like that

```
foreach ($user_list_array as $key = $val) {
    echo $val["first_name"];
    $user_list_array[$key]["last_name"] = "test";
}
```